# I can't start my Ubuntu. I have set my computer in dual mode, Ubuntu and Windows. I tried to open Ubuntu as usual, and it appears the following Alert:

Tags: boot

**ALERT! UUID=1d910c6e-f57e-4e1b-bdb6-7390c0bf22e8 does not exist. Dropping to shell!**

[ALERT! Can't Open Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEHNS.jpg)

Then I started in a "recovery mode" and I ran the following 2 codes:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Then I reboot and the problem continues the same

Does anyone know what could I do?

Comment: You need to boot from a LiveUSB and fix UUID in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: A change has been made to your *file-system table* (`fstab`) OR your system's partitions/partition-table & your `fstab` was NOT altered to make allowance for the change.  Both need to be put back in sync!   Do note:  If you're not aware of any change that caused this, then this issue is very likely a *symptom* of a problem & needs to be explored asap, and not just quickly *averted* & *ignored*.  I'd expect you'd know what caused this (ie. what changed) otherwise you've an *problem* to track down with your hardware.